# Insert data from pandas into sql db - keys doesn't fit columns

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a database with around 10 columns. Sometimes I need to insert a row which has only 3 of the required columns, the rest are not in the `dic`.

The data to be inserted is a dictionary named `row` :
(this insert is to avoid duplicates)

```py
row = {'keyword':'abc','name':'bds'.....}
df = pd.DataFrame([row]) # df looks good, I see columns and 1 row.
engine  = getEngine()
connection = engine.connect()
df.to_sql('temp_insert_data_index', connection, if_exists ='replace',index=False)
result = connection.execute(('''
        INSERT INTO {t} SELECT * FROM temp_insert_data_index 
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING''').format(t=table_name))
connection.close()
```

**Problem** : when I don't have all columns in the `row`(dic), it will insert `dic` fields *by order* (a 3 keys dic will be inserted *to the first 3 columns*) and not to the right columns. ( I expect the keys in dic to fit the db columns)

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider explicitly naming the columns to be inserted in `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT` clauses which is best practice for SQL append queries. Doing so, the dynamic query should work for all or subset of columns. Below uses F-string (available Python 3.6+) for all interpolation to larger SQL query:

```py
# APPEND TO STAGING TEMP TABLE
df.to_sql('temp_insert_data_index', connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# STRING OF COMMA SEPARATED COLUMNS
cols = ", ".join(df.columns)

sql = (
    f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({cols}) "
    f"SELECT {cols} FROM temp_insert_data_index "
    "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
)
result = connection.execute(sql)
connection.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still didn't understand where was my mistake ? why my data frame will not be written into columns? and what 'cols' does here?

Comment: oh I see. thanks a lot!